# Как проверить нагрузочную способность телеграм бота на python?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, testng

Написал ТГ бота на Python который обращается к sqlite каждый раз при нажатии на кнопку.
Велика вероятность, что одновременно им будут пользоваться около 50чел.
Как проверить выдержит ли бот такую нагрузку?

Я знаю, что это можно сделать с помощью Jmeter, но к сожалению не смог найти понятного объяснения.

Comment: Возможно, вам нужно узнать про асинхронное программирование в питоне. Тогда проблем даже с единовременной обработкой быть не должно

Comment: Он полностью асинхронен. Но я такой человек, что хочется всегда перестраховаться)

Comment: 50 человек — это вообще не нагрузка. Тем не менее, если хотя бы 2 будут одновременно писать в базу, можно словить deadlock. Соответственно надо предусмотреть этот сценарий, либо использовать другую БД, где писать можно одновременно. Что до стресс-теста, не знаю зачем тут Jmeter, можно просто колошматить бота [REST запросами](https://unbiased-coder.com/load-test-api-with-python/). Готовых [судя по всему нет](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73518293/load-testing-python-bot-in-telegram), и правильный там совет дают, лучше попробовать написать самому и использовать несколько машин.

Comment: Спасибо, запись в базу у меня не идёт. Идут только SELECT запросы, но очень часто. Попробую

Answer (score 0):

Насчет стрессеров - лучшего нет, чем реальное использование, да и 50 человек это мало для ботов.

Написал маленький код, который можно вызывать в нужном месте вашего бота, так же два варианта - вывод либо в консоль, либо в сообщении от бота.

```
import psutil

def monitor_resources():
    # Получаем использование CPU, RAM, дискового пространства
    cpu_percent = psutil.cpu_percent()
    ram_percent = psutil.virtual_memory().percent
    disk_percent = psutil.disk_usage('/').percent

    # Выводим информацию в консоль или в лог-файл
    print(f"CPU: {cpu_percent}%")
    print(f"RAM: {ram_percent}%")
    print(f"Disk: {disk_percent}%")

    # Можно также отправить информацию в бота в виде сообщения
    #bot.send_message(chat_id, f"CPU: {cpu_percent}%\nRAM: {ram_percent}%\nDisk: {disk_percent}%")
```

Comment: Спасибо, наверно буду в txt файл закидывать